# Jquery set variable input field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML:

```
<input id="penge" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: paymentwindow.open()" value="BETAL" id="betal" />
```

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var penge = $("#penge").val();


            paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({
                         'amount': penge,
                         'currency': "DKK",
                         'language': "1",
                         'orderid': "155",
                         'callbackurl': "http://localhost:3000/"
            });
});
</script>
```

The variable is undefined. I want to set the variable penge when the betal button is clicked.

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var penge;
$('#betal').click(function(){
    penge = $("#penge").val();
    paymentwindow.open();
});




            paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({
                         'amount': penge,
                         'currency': "DKK",
                         'language': "1",
                         'orderid': "155",
                         'callbackurl': "http://localhost:3000/"
            });
});
</script>
```

Penge is undefined. I have also removed the onclick js for the betal button.

Comment: Hey man, whats the `type` of your input?

Comment: @Tats_innit. The default is `text`...

Comment: The value is integer the type is text

Comment: You want to set the value to...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently input field value is empty.

Enter some amount in the input field then click on `betal` button.

You will get an alert with the value entered on input field.

Do your stuff with the `penge` variable which is stored with your value.

```
var penge;
$('#betal').click(function(){     
    penge = $("#penge").val();     
    alert(penge);
});
```

### HTML:

```
<input id="penge" /> 
<input type="button" value="BETAL" id="betal" />
```

Refer this **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/F9ZVu/)**

### UPDATED:

I got your issue. Call the `paymentwindow.open();` after the payment method declaration.

```
var penge;
var paymentwindow;
$('#betal').click(function(){
    var penge = $("#penge").val();
    paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({
        amount: penge,
        currency: "DKK",
        language: "1",
        orderid: "155",
        callbackurl: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    });
    paymentwindow.open();    
});
```

Refer this **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/tdgM8/13/)**

Comment: See it does not work with the payment window the varible is undefined: jsfiddle.net/tdgM8/6

Comment: @Railsbeginner: I got your issue, refer to my demo 2 at updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var penge;
$('#betal').click(function(){
    var penge = $("#penge").val();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdgM8/2)

Comment: I need the value for the input field, not some value. I have tried to remove the some value. But then it is undefined.

Comment: @Railsbeginner. What is the value you need...?

Comment: @gdoron the value of the input field. I have just updated what I have tried.

Comment: @Railsbeginner. Which input? try to be clearer please. The textbox? you need to put some text there first.

Comment: @Railsbeginner. Then use this `penge = $("#penge").val();` just make sure the textbox has value

Comment: I think the value also need to be in double quotes

Comment: I think it is overkill to call `.val` twice. `$("#penge").val(penge = 'some value');` also works.

Comment: @pimvdb. It's just an example and the `val` for one input is really not overkill, just 0.00000001 But, I'll change as yours is better.

Comment: @gordon have to put dobble quotes? (escape)

Comment: @Railsbeginner. Put what where? Did you see the DEMO? it work doesn't it.

Comment: Still the value is "undefined"

Comment: @Railsbeginner.You don't need to escape the "" there. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tdgM8/4/). BTW, why are you adding them?

Comment: @Railsbeginner. Put it inside the click handler [DEMO once again](http://jsfiddle.net/tdgM8/9/).

Comment: @gdoron your js fiddle does not work, nothing happens when betal button is clicked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12964/discussion-between-gdoron-and-rails-beginner)